# Mock not properly worked

Tags: java, android, mockito

I want to use TDD in my current app and try to create some tests. In this case I need to send message to support, and if it will ok return `true`. But when I start my tests I get fail, because actual and expected result are not the same.

When I debug this test, I see, that mockito put Mocks as I need, but `sender.sendSupportMessage()` steel return false. Can anybody explain me what's going wrong?

```
public class SupportTests {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    SupportContract.ISupportMessageSender sender;
    @Mock
    CurrentUserOperations currentUserOperations;

    private SupportMessage stubSupportMessage;
    private String message;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        message = "message";
        stubSupportMessage = new SupportMessage(1, message, null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMessageToSupportShouldBeDone (){
        Support support = new Support(sender, currentUserOperations); 

        when(currentUserOperations.getCurrentUserSystemId())
            .thenReturn(Long.valueOf(1));
        when(sender.sendSupportMessage(stubSupportMessage))
            .thenReturn(true);

        boolean actualResult = support.sendMessageToSupport(message);

        assertEquals("Sending message to support are failed.", true, actualResult);
    }

}


public class Support implements SupportContract.ISupport {

    private SupportContract.ISupportMessageSender sender;
    private CurrentUserOperations currentUserOperations;

    public Support(SupportContract.ISupportMessageSender sender, CurrentUserOperations currentUserOperations) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.currentUserOperations = currentUserOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendMessageToSupport(String message) {
        long userSystemId = currentUserOperations.getCurrentUserSystemId();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        SupportMessage supportMessage = new SupportMessage(userSystemId, message,
            dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

        return sender.sendSupportMessage(supportMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found solution.

As we see, in TestMethod we use `stubSupportMessage`, which instantiated in `@Before init` method.

Also, in the `Support` class we see `SupportMessage supportMessage = new SupportMessage(...)`, and these support messages are not the same `stubSupportMessage != supportMessage`.

So, we need to get rid of the different objects. Problem was solved by this code:

```
when(sender.sendSupportMessage(any(SupportMessage.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

Where we say `any` object of `SupportMessage` class can be used.

Test class now:

```
public class SupportTests {

@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Mock
SupportContract.ISupportMessageSender sender;
@Mock
CurrentUserOperations currentUserOperations;

private String message;

@Before
public void init(){
    message = "message";
}

@Test
public void testSendMessageToSupportShouldBeDone (){
    Support support = new Support(sender, currentUserOperations);

    when(currentUserOperations.getCurrentUserSystemId()).thenReturn(Long.valueOf(1));
    when(sender.sendSupportMessage(any(SupportMessage.class))).thenReturn(true);

    boolean actualResult = support.sendMessageToSupport(message);

    assertEquals("Sending message to support are failed.", true, actualResult);
}

}
```